# Tailing multiple files with less

Tags: less, tail

I want to have the best of both worlds with `tail` and `less`.
Following multiple files, like `tail` can, but also having the scrollable buffer of `less`.

So, I tried:

```
tail -f mylog1 mylog2 | less +F
```

But this only gives me a blank screen until I interrupt. Doing "shift-F" again doesn't help.

How do I do this? It seems to me that following stdin shouldn't be that hard for less?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- [MultiTail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) MultiTail lets you view one or multiple files like the original tail program. The difference is that it creates multiple windows on your console (with ncurses).
- Use `screen` to create multiple windows; then run `tail` (or even better, `less -F`) in each of them